# Spark Local Session with custom maven library

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, sbt, local

In my scala code, which I run thru sbt run command I am creating local spark session and I need to make use of following library: com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.17

My code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._

...

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("RandomForestClassifierExample")
      .getOrCreate()

...

  val connectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder("<connectionstring>")
    .setEventHubName("energinet")
    .build
  val eventHubsConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString)
    .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream)
    .setConsumerGroup("$default")

  val eventhubs = spark.readStream
    .format("eventhubs")
    .options(eventHubsConf.toMap)
    .load()
```

Of course it fails, because of missing event hubs library. I know I can run spark-submit and pull the library by setting --packages parameter, however I want to run my app using sbt run command. Please is there a way, how to make the library available for local spark sessions I create from scala code?

Comment: Yes, the same way to you would add any other library to your code, like **Spark** itself, adding it as a dependency in your build system _(e.g. sbt or maven)_.

Comment: thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez for some reason I was blocked on approach to install in to the cluster